# Getting a confirmation message if file is saved phpexcel

Tags: php

How to get confirmation message if phpexcel succeed with saving a file.
I'm trying to export database results to excel file wih phpexcel.

I want to get a confirmation message if the file is saved.

I have something like this

```
$writer->save('files/users.xlsx');
```

I tried to use if, for example

```
if($writer->save('files/users.xlsx')){
   echo "Saved";
}
```

But it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

When checking the [source code of the Excel2007 writer](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php) I noticed that the save() method does indeed return nothing. But there are numerous Exceptions thrown if anything goes wrong. This means that you should be able to try-catch the call to save() to find out if something went wrong during the file save:

```
try {
    $writer->save('files/users.xlsx');
    echo "Saved";
} catch (PHPExcel_Writer_Exception $e) {
    echo "Something went wrong: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```